# Laravel search function to filter foreign key data by keywords

Tags: laravel

I have a table in my database, which contains only foreign keys. I want to create a search function to filter the data using keywords.

Can anyone solve this ?

Thank you.

This is my table:

vehicle_table :

```
id | model_id | variant_id
1  | 1        | 1
```

model_table :

```
id | make_id | name 
1  | 1       | Beat
```

make_table :

```
id | name 
1  | Chevrolet
```

variant_table :

```
id | name 
1  | 1.0 PS
```

Comment: Post your code what you tried for this!

Comment: Can you add details about the foreign key and tables structures in details ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please provide what have you tried till now to understand your problem. According to what I've understood, you can build a query for vehicle_table and join your others table and do your filters like below:

```
$vehicles = DB::table('vehicle_table')
            ->select('model_table.name as model_name', 'make_table.name as make_name', 'variant_table.name as variant_name')
            ->leftJoin('model_table','model_table.id','=', 'vehicle_table.model_id')
            ->leftJoin('make_table','make_table.id','=', 'model_table.make_id')
            ->leftJoin('variant_table','variant_table.id','=', 'vehicle_table.variant_id');
if($make_name){
    $vehicles->where('make_table.name', 'like', '%' . $make_name . '%');
}

if($model_name){
    $vehicles->where('model_table.name', 'like', '%' . $model_name . '%');
}

if($variant_name){
    $vehicles->where('variant_table.name', 'like', '%' . $variant_name . '%');
}

$results = $vehicles->get();
```

`$make_name, $model_name, $variant_name` would be your search form values.

--UPDATE--
If you want to search string(more than one word) through all tables you can do the following:

```
$words = explode(' ', $search);
$vehicles = DB::table('vehicle_table')
                ->select('model_table.name as model_name', 'make_table.name as make_name', 'variant_table.name as variant_name')
                ->leftJoin('model_table','model_table.id','=', 'vehicle_table.model_id')
                ->leftJoin('make_table','make_table.id','=', 'model_table.make_id')
                ->leftJoin('variant_table','variant_table.id','=', 'vehicle_table.variant_id');
foreach($words as $word){
    $vehicles->where('make_table.name', 'like', '%' . $word. '%');
    $vehicles->orWhere('model_table.name', 'like', '%' . $word. '%');
    $vehicles->orWhere('variant_table.name', 'like', '%' . $word. '%');
}    
$results = $vehicles->get();
```

Comment: This is working. But I need one parameter to search make, model and variant. instead of $make_name, $model_name, $variant_name. How can I do this?

Comment: $users->where('make_table.name', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
        ->orWhere('model_table.name', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
        ->orWhere('variant_table.name', 'like', '%' . $search . '%');

I'm doing like this, but it's working for single word. I want to search make, model & variant all at once. it's not taking multiple words.